# Client side or Server Side - React (App for a customer)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

i have a quick question, so i just built 3 websites for customers using React and they're all deployed and working but now one of these customers is asking me how they can update its content, all the website are stored either on one or many JS files after building them with npm run build and configured with webpack, how should i build a website where customers plan to change either texts or add new images? the websites have a couple of map functions to display many pictures or card based on products, so everytime theres a change i have to go through the react files and change them build it again and deploy them which seems pretty static to me even though React is supposed to work with components and make it dynamic, what would be the best approach and/or tools to build a website where a customer can change a .JS file with text in Cpanel file manager, or just add pictures to a directory in Cpanel file manager and have it render automatically, i was thinking that i should make it server side so i can avoid having to re build and re upload everytime that there are changes, bu what would be the best options besides React to make it dynamic, Should i use node, express??

Thank you so much for your time !

Comment: You don't want customers messing with JS files.  You want a database feeding information into the app, and an Admin page where customers can modify records in that database.  What you're describing is essentially a CMS, and depending on the extent of edits they wish to make, can be a very large task to build from scratch.

Comment: @JakeHaller-Roby  the JS files im talking about are just a const = with different objects that are mapped as arrays like: ``` const = artists { id:1, info:"foo", link1:"url" }``` which is pretty easy to fill with new information, and yes i was thinking they basically need a CMS, i just want to give them the chance to update just basic stuff, like the about text, maybe the main js file where its pulling the data to map, and just add new images and have the functions i already wrote work with the new files without having to rebuild

Comment: @JakeHaller-Roby What should i add to my existing code to make a small CMS where i can just change the content of a couple of texts and add images to a directory? i just want them to be able to change just like 4 things in the website

Answer (score 0):

One of the options could be Contentful API, you can store all of your data there and add permission to your customer to edit the repo. This will make it easier to change the content that you mentioned: "*the websites have a couple of map functions to display many pictures or card based on products*". So what you will do is simply fetch data from the API and render it on your website, this will allow your Customers to CRUD the content of your website, without your intervention. It is pretty easy to use, you can find out more about it here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/.

Regarding the content of the website itself, e.g pages, texts on pages, and other static stuff that does not depend on actual data, but it's only a part of your code, I think it could be hard to manage without you coding it manually. If there is an exact part of content data that is going to be changed, you could make a new **Admin** page, where the user will be able to change the content and data on your website, and in this could you will have to add some back-end (node, express, etc). But what you're describing is actually CMS which is really popular nowadays you might want to take a look at some of them:

- https://www.wix.com/
- https://wordpress.com/

But if the **Texts** that you've mentioned are just a part of models e.g You have a product with something like this:

```
const product = {
   productName: 'name',
   price: '100',
   image: 'img',
   avialable: false,
}
```

and clients want to change *productName*, *price*, *image*, *avialability* then Contentful is pretty sufficient for you. If you will need some help with this Platform you can DM me I will try to help you.

Comment: yes, basically they wanted a highly customized website with animations and css, and wordpress and wix are just too heavy to load for a small website due to all the plugins, themes, and many functions we dont really need for these projects, and also if i used wix or wordpress they wouldnt even need me in the first place to build them, i will read the link you sent me to try to understand it a bit more and be able to just build a simple cms where they have just a very limited set of options to change like 5 maximum

Comment: If they need to add animations and change styles and other stuff which basically depends on code, then you should think something more than just administration. What you're talking about is just a new *CMS*, in other words, they want you to build your own, but simple **WordPress** or **Wix**.

Comment: Take a look at my repo, the project recently I built is something like I described above, I used Netlify and Email.JS for sending emails for admin and clients without any use of any back-end (node, express). Here is the link: https://github.com/Mirazyzz/Hostel-Booking

Comment: The animations and styles are already set as i designed their logos and branding etc, i just want them to be able to CRUD just like 3 pieces of texts(i.e. about, a product list with objects like the one you submitted (product), and allow them to upload pictures to one directory, thanks so much for your time, i will dig deeper into your answer, if i have any more questions ill definitely DM you!, thank u so much @miraziz :)

Comment: awesome, will look into your repo :)

Comment: Sure, if you need any further help, just DM me. Wish you luck with your project ;)